# Django modelform is not inserting data

Tags: python, django

I have a Modelform that works great and the redirect happens normally without raising an error. but the data is not inserted into the table, here are my files :

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # custom validators
    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

    # fields
    dress_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, verbose_name='وصف الفستان',
                                  help_text='مثال: فستان سواريه احمر')
    dress_size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete='DO_NOTHING', verbose_name='مقاس الفستان')
    dress_color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete='DO_NOTHING', verbose_name='لون الفستان')
    dress_image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=False, verbose_name='الصورة الأساسية للفستان',
                                     help_text='لا يمكنك تركها فارغة')
    dress_image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, verbose_name='صورة إضافية ')
    dress_image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, verbose_name='صورة إضافة ')
    dress_action = models.ForeignKey(Action, on_delete='DO_NOTHING', verbose_name='الفستان معروض لل ',
                                     help_text='للبيع او للإيجار ')
    dress_price = models.IntegerField(default=1, verbose_name='السعر')
    dress_country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete='CASCADE', verbose_name='البلد')
    dress_city = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='المدينة او المحافظة')
    dress_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20, validators=[alphanumeric], verbose_name='رقم الهاتف ')
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=250,)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    dress_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dress_special = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dress_name
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddDressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ['created_by', 'created_at','dress_active','dress_special']
```

**views.py**

```
def add_dress(request):
    current_user = request.user
    all_dress = Item.objects.all()
    all_dress_s = Item.objects.all().filter(dress_special=True)
    if request.method == "POST":
        add_dress_form = AddDressForm(request.POST)
        if add_dress_form.is_valid():
            model_instance = add_dress_form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.created_by = current_user
            model_instance.save()
        return redirect('home')

    else:
        add_cat_form = AddDressForm()

    context = {
            'add_cat_form': add_cat_form,
            'current_user': current_user,
            'all_dress': all_dress,
            'all_dress_s': all_dress_s,
        }

    return render(request, "fostania/add_dress.html", context)
```

I just need to know what is missing inside the code that simply let the request pass with no errors but never insert data into table!

**form in template **

```
 <form action="" method="post" name="AddDressForm" align="right">
{% csrf_token %}

{% for field in add_cat_form %}
{{ field.label_tag }}&nbsp;{{ field }}&nbsp;{{ feild.help_text }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100px;" value="إضافة" />
        </form>
```

Comment: can you post your form? this `fostania/add_dress.html`

Comment: Done, updated question

Comment: try `Item.objects.count()` in your shell. if it retuns some number otherthan zero then your code is working fine. (above code should work)

Comment: Try commenting out the redirect code. If there are some errors, now you will be able to see on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
    if add_dress_form.is_valid():
        model_instance = add_dress_form.save(commit=False)
        model_instance.created_by = current_user
        model_instance.save()
    return redirect('home')
```

Your are unconditionnally redirecting whether the form is valid or not. You want only want to redirect if the form was valid:

```
    if add_dress_form.is_valid():
        model_instance = add_dress_form.save(commit=False)
        model_instance.created_by = current_user
        model_instance.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

And you also want to make sure you display form errors in your template, cf https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html